# convert 2020-01-22 00:00:00+00:00 into 2020-01-22 using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i need to  time format from `2020-01-22 00:00:00+00:00` to `2020-01-22` using pandas,
this is not just a line of code put it is a data-frame.

**the code is:**

```
confirmed_file=pd.read_json('https://api.covid19api.com/country/egypt/status/confirmed/live')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
confirmed_file = pd.read_json(
    "https://api.covid19api.com/country/egypt/status/confirmed/live"
)
confirmed_file["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(confirmed_file["Date"]).dt.date
print(confirmed_file)
```

Prints:

```
    Country CountryCode Province City CityCode    Lat   Lon   Cases     Status        Date
0     Egypt          EG                         26.82  30.8       0  confirmed  2020-01-22
1     Egypt          EG                         26.82  30.8       0  confirmed  2020-01-23
2     Egypt          EG                         26.82  30.8       0  confirmed  2020-01-24
3     Egypt          EG                         26.82  30.8       0  confirmed  2020-01-25
4     Egypt          EG                         26.82  30.8       0  confirmed  2020-01-26

...and so on.
```